# Using GraphQL useQuery Variables

Tags: graphql, gql

I'm currently on client side trying to make a query but can't go through. However it works when testing at the back-end.

- [back-end docs & getting response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa4XD.jpg)
- front-end code (getting 400 code)

`` const QUERY_SPECIFIC_CATEGORY_PRODUCTS = gql` query QUERY_SPECIFIC_CATEGORY_PRODUCTS($category: String!) { category(input: { title: $category }) { name } } `; const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(QUERY_SPECIFIC_CATEGORY_PRODUCTS, { //   prettier-ignore variables: {input: { title: "clothes" }} }); ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `useQuery` just pass the "clothes" value as the `category` variable:

```
const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(QUERY_SPECIFIC_CATEGORY_PRODUCTS, {
  variables: { category: "clothes" },
});
```